# Проект не видит HttpLoggingInterceptor

Tags: java, android, retrofit

Использую `Retrofit2`, обновила `build.gradle` после этого проект перестал находить `HttpLoggingInterceptor`, В `build.gradle` секция `dependencies` сейчас выглядит вот так:

```
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.2.0'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.6.0'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.6.0'
```

Что нужно поменять в `build.gradle`, что бы проект снова мог найти `HttpLoggingInterceptor` ?

Код, где используется `HttpLogginInterceptor`:

```
 public BaseApi() {
        HeaderInterceptor headerInterceptor = new HeaderInterceptor();
        HttpLoggingInterceptor logger = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
        logger.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
        client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .connectTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .readTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .addInterceptor(logger)
                .addInterceptor(headerInterceptor)
                .build();

        retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BuildConfig.BASE_URL)
                .client(client)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.create())
                .build();

        service = retrofit.create(MessengerApi.class);
    }
```

Comment: @rjhdby Проект выдает ошибку при импорте okhttp3.logging.HttpLoggingInterceptor; loggin подсвечивается красным.

Comment: @Lucky_girl, а если так попробовать? `compile('com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0') {
        exclude module: 'okhttp'
    }`

Comment: @rjhdby Добавила код, под ошибкой я имею ввиду, ошибку импорта, проект не видит okhttp3.logging.HttpLoggingInterceptor

Comment: @ЮрийСПб все равно не видит этот класс

Comment: @Lucky_girl тогда стандартные танцы с бубном: Clean project, Invalidate caches/Restart, синхронизация gradle

Comment: А если этим строкам false везде задать где они с true? `minifyEnabled false
shrinkResources false`

Comment: @ЮрийСПб это только на этапе компиляции может навредить, но не на этапе расставления импортов

Comment: Уберите все импорты (удалите), сделайте рестарт студии, далее наведите на `HttpLoggingInterceptor` и нажмите *alt-enter*

Comment: @rjhdby Стандартные танцы с бубном помогли, после Invalidate caches/Restart - все заработало!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Android Studio в своей основе имеет IntelliJ IDEA, в которой такие ситуации переодически возникают.

Если вдруг IDE перестала вести себя адекватно, не видит классов, не хочет правильно расставлять импорты - есть ряд действий, которые могут привести её в чувство:

1. File > Invalidate Caches / Restart. Обычно этого хватает.
2. Build > Clean project. Это помогает когда IDE не видит ресурсов `R.*`
3. Изредка спасает пересинхронизация Gradle (очень редко, но у меня пару раз случалось)